# Deallocating memory to avoid memory leaks

Tags: visual-c++, memory, memory-leaks

I have found where some of my memory leaks are but I cant figure out how to fix them. There are a few cases where I create local Char * using new but then I need to use delete to deallocate the memory (correct?) within the scope. I have added this in a couple spots but I am still getting a memory leak. I also created a function that converts an entire char * to lowercase and created a another temporary char * to hold it and then return it at the end of the function. Where should I delete it since I am returning it? (I know I am getting a memory leak here)

ToLower funcion:

```
char * item::ToLower(char * source)
{
    int length = strlen(source) + 1;
    char * dest = new char[length + 1];

    for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
    {
        if (source[index] == ' ')
            dest[index] = ' ';
        else
            dest[index] = tolower(source[index]);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

another questions:
in this assignment the instuctor says there should only be one return per method (function), and we are using bool return types. I thought that each path should have a return, is this not true? is it better to just put a return at the end? any suggestions or thoughts would be helpfull.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using a `std::string`?

Comment: In this case, you can operate directly on `source`, it's not `const` so there's no need to allocate any memory.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Are you calling it with `source = ToLower(source)` by any chance?

Comment: we cannot use string in this assignment, we must use char *. ToLower is defined in my "item" class, so the call is to_add.ToLower(to_add.get_name()) for example. I don't want to actually change the formatting of the char * being passed in, that is why I create a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

When returning a raw pointer allocated you are effectively throwing the responsibility of the deletion on the caller of this function (it is not clear whether you're writing code that is only used internally by you or could there be some 3rd party user).

If you are only using it internally you should `delete` it the moment you're finished using it.

If you are writing something that can be used by others then you can only ask them nicely and hope for the best.

In case you can change the methods signature I'd advise you to use [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) depending on your needs.

Also if you do not intend to change `source` in any way use `const char * const source`.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> ToLower2(const char * const source)
{
    int length = strlen(source) + 1;
    char * dest = new char[length + 1];
    for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
    {
        if (source[index] == ' ')
            dest[index] = ' ';
        else
            dest[index] = tolower(source[index]);
    }
     return std::unique_ptr<char[]>(dest);
}
```

You can see an example [here](http://ideone.com/nrEIeF)(it does work on VS2010 as well).

As for the sub-question regarding returns, you are correct "all paths" should have a `return`(unless of course it's a `void` function which can have none), one `return` is more a style which can be more convenient to some and less to others.